# Variable value in the mail in script in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a Adf flow , in which, i have stored the data in a array Variable(namely 'VariOutput'), that thing is present in a If Condition Activity.

and in IF condition False Activity , i have given the Web activity link. the code used is

'''{
"RunId":"Dummy",
"applicationName": "@{pipeline().parameters.AppName}",
"ErrorCode":"error",
"ErrorMessage":@{concat('File/Files not found-', string(variables('VariOutput')))},
}'''

But the webactivity is not processing the Array Variable **VariOutput** and throwing an error.

[image]

error :: error": {
"code": "InvalidRequestContent",
"message": "The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: F. Path 'ErrorMessage

**ignore the line number 7 in the error , as i have deleted part of the error.**
[image]

Comment: Try this `@concat('File/Files not found-', string(variables('VariOutput')))`

Comment: The function call must take the completion string(13) , gives this error when i pass above code

Comment: can you share sample input and output for better understanding?

Comment: Try this `@{concat('File/Files not found-', replace(string(variables('VariOutput')),'"',''''))}` in error message

Comment: same error again @aswin

Comment: Can you share the input of web activity. Refer this [step:1](https://i.imgur.com/2Eq5E8R.png) and [step:2](https://i.imgur.com/QfhXnaA.png) and share the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: F. Path 'ErrorMessage

- I tried to repro this and got the same error.

[image]

- This is because of double quotes in the variable. Replace the double quotes with single quotes and pass it in the web activity.
- Give the below expression for **error message**
  `"ErrorMessage":"@{concat('File/Files not found-', replace(string(variables('VariOutput')),'"',''''))}"`

[image]

- When the pipeline is debugged, it is executed successfully, and mail is sent.

[image]

Comment: Hi Aswin , can you try Array variable , cause i seee the issue with Array variable only 

keep ["1","2","3","4"] as the VariOutput. then i get this error

Comment: Even for this input, It works fine.

Comment: If you get error, share the input of web activity. Refer this [step:1](https://i.imgur.com/2Eq5E8R.png) and [step:2](https://i.imgur.com/QfhXnaA.png)

Comment: Are you getting the same error?

Comment: thanks aswin, the issue gets resolved when i use this  as suggested by you.

"Attachment":"@{pipeline().parameters.Attachment}",
"mailBody":"<html>
                      <body>
                      <p>Hi All,</p>
                      <p>Error message: @{variables('ErrorVariable')}</p>
                      <p>Error message2:@{concat('File not Found',replace(string(variables('HelloVariable')),'"',''))}</p>